# Else If's logical equivalence

Tags: java, logic

Is there ever a case where:

```
if (condition) {
    statement
} else {
    if (condition2) {
        statement
    } else {
        statement
    }
}
```

Is not equivalent to:

```
if (condition) {
    statement
} else if (condition2) {
    statement
} else {
    statement
}
```

If there is a case I am struggling to find the case. If anyone knows of a counter example or if they are definitely equivalent your input would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: No, those two statements are equivalent.

Comment: Only when someone comes along later and erroneously edits your poorly-indented code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two statements in your question are exactly the same. That said, the first statement is more useful when you want to perform some common steps before entering the `if-else` block again. For example :

```
if (condition) {
    statement
} else {
    perform some common steps.
    if (condition2) {
        statement
    } else {
        statement
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Both of the conditional structures are equal.

In first case you have more options like you can execute some code for case where either second if or else turns to be true that block must execute.

```
if (condition1) {
    ...
} else {
    ...
    if (condition2) {
        ...
    } else {
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```

But first is more simple to read.

You can alternatively use switch as well that is more performance efficient.

Comment: Isn't the first one less efficient than the second one because of how processors work?

Answer (score 0):

No, those are always exactly equivalent.

The *reason* they're exactly equivalent is that the only statement in the block in your first example is the one `if` statement; so removing the block doesn't change the semantics at all, as it's only wrapping one statement without any variable declarations, etc. along with it.

Contrast with:

```
if (condition) {
    statement
} else {
    String foo = "bar";
    if (condition2) {
        statement
    } else {
        statement
    }
}
```

Now the block is doing something in addition to the single `if` in your version, and so things have diverged.

But since your version doesn't have *anything* other than the `if`, they're exactly the same.

Answer (score 0):

the brackets after the else are unecessary since after that there is one instruction (the second if), so unless you parse the java file for some reason afterwards the should be no case in which they are different in any context

Answer (score 0):

A condition is either true or false. There are only four options four two conditions to be.
In both cases exactly one of the three statements will be executed and it is the same in both cases, as you can try out using all four options. 
So even if the statement would have an influence on the condition, this would not have an effect. Therefore I bet it is equivalent.